# What is the recommended method to simplify trigonometric expressions like $\frac{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fractions

Is there an algorithm or preferred method to simplify these expressions?

$$\frac{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta}\quad\text{and}\quad \frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha+\cos\beta}$$

I tried to manipulate them using double and sum but none of them seemed to help.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I've seen the formulae you had just mentioned but it shows it in a straightforward way, could it be a way to solve my problem with the use of simpler identities?.

Comment: These are basically the same; replacing $\beta$ in one by $\beta+\pi$ gives the other, so if you can reduce one according to your taste, you can reduce the other.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{\sin\alpha-\sin\beta}{\cos\alpha-\cos\beta}=\frac{2\sin\frac{\alpha-\beta}{2}\cos\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}{2\sin\frac{\beta-\alpha}{2}\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}}=-\cot\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}.$$
The second is similar.

Comment: I see you have used the formula referred earlier in the comments but isn't there any other shortcut? What if it involves secant or cosecant instead of cosine and sine?

Comment: @Chris Steinbeck Bell Maybe there is. In trigonometry sometimes there are many ways to get the answer. Just $-\cot\frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$ seems easier than starting expression.